# RTMP streaming without flash and low latency

Tags: html, flash, ffmpeg, stream, rtmp

I have a server that currently streams out RTMP media and I need to play it with minimum delay (2-3 seconds).
Now I'm using CRTMPServer to consume the stream but, since there is no RTMP player without flash dependency, this solutions does not work for me because I need to play it embedded into a web page.

At this point, I tried Nimble Streamer but I only could consume HLS, DASH and SLDP. HLS and DASH has 10 second delay so I discard these approaches.
SLDP has low latency but is a closed protocol and there is only one player (closed but freeware).

On the other hand, there is RTSP but there are no HTML5 players for it. But I couldn't consume RTSP streams from Nimble neither.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Webrtc or single frame fragments over web socket.

Comment: @szatmary Do you know any WebRTC server?

Comment: I understand you want to embed in a web page and there seems no other alternatives. In the past I've used UDPXY (https://angrytechnician.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/converting-your-multicast-iptv-freeview-to-http-unicast-using-udpxy/) which is a http proxy for IPTV.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know why you discarded Nimble Streamer, I've tried it and it has a delay of 2 or 3 seconds.
My tests were with more than 200 attendees in Full HD (1280)
And the results were incredible, it has relatively low consumption of resources, the only thing you have to take into account is the bandwidth.

They have a protocol that allows them to have a delay of 2 or 3 seconds.
Look:
https://es.wmspanel.com/nimble/sldp

So Nimble Stream seems like a good option.
regards

Comment: Yes, SLDP's latency is awesome but I'm looking for something with more support than just one player for a closed protocol. Its just a business decision (and not mine).

Comment: I doubt you will find a better system, with low latency and stable.
I'm currently working with streaming and all the systems I've tried (which have been many) Nimble is the one that has given me results.
However, if you find a good solution, you can share it.

Comment: Alfredo, thanks for the feedback, we appreciate that. In fact, our customers have sub-second delay with SLDP after tuning the GOP size and other parameters on both transcoder and player side. You can check this article for details of player side as example: http://blog.wmspanel.com/2017/08/decrease-start-time-sldp-using-offset.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm Yury from Softvelum, which is the company behind Nimble Streamer and SLDP technology.
You mention

> SLDP has low latency but is a closed protocol and there is only one
>   player (closed but freeware).

We currently have 3 players - HTML5/JavaScript, Android and iOS, they all are being actively developed at the moment. All 3 players have their SDKs which means you can extend their behavior in any way you like and use in your own apps and web pages. We currently communicate with other existing players in order to extend the reach of SLDP technology.

At the moment when we started creating the SLDP architecture, there were no publicly available technologies to cover low-latency last-mile scenarios while our customers strove for that all the time. That's why we implemented SLDP and our goal is not just to provide the technology but to make it available for broader audience. We cannot accomplish this by ourselves alone, hence the SDK and other initiatives. We're opened for collaboration with any other companies on this market.

If SLDP works fine for your use case, don't hesitate to use further - we have big plans for it and you can be sure it will be supported and improved by our company. Of course, your feedback is highly welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You can install one webserver with RTMP module like

Nginx+RTMP module

If have Windows 10 Pro then can use Ubuntu WSL(linux for windows) 18.04 bionic

Then can use OBS to can streaming your laptop's desktop or your laptop's webcam or other media resurse to Nginx(which have RTMP module installed)
Then as player=render you can use VLC player or can push the stream to FB,YT ... or other webservice live

OBS--->>--->NgInx(+RTMP module)--->>-->VLC player or FB,YT live